# Python style: for-in syntax, checking for empty lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, list, idioms

I'm new to python and haven't yet read a lot of code to verify which styles are considered 'pythonic'.

As I've started to code, I've been using this pattern alot.

```
listThatMightBeEmpty = []
for items in listThatMightBeEmpty:
    print "this may or may not print but the loop won't cause any errors"
```

I assume that it would be redundant to first check if the list is empty - that I can just let the for-in loop do nothing if the list is empty.  But I want to make sure there aren't any gotchas for any situation including using old versions of python, and including using a for-in loop on dictionaries, using enumerate(), or iteritems(), or using list comprehensions etc.

Comment: I tend to keep an interactive python session open in a different window while I'm coding, so if I am curious about a particular case, I can just experiment as I go. This particular question, though, is one you want to know generally, and the answer is, pretty much, no gotchas. It's perfectly possible to create an object that acts like a list except it raises an exception if accessed when empty, or returns the string "418 I'm a teapot", or something else surprising, but that would be a very unusual and unpythonic case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right. There are no gotchas here. You can use it on an empty list.

- Old but still holds good : http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a list is empty, you can do this:

```
>>> x = []
>>> if not x:
         # do something
```

If the list is empty, `# do something` will run and you can handle the execution there.

However, there is nothing wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is redundant (unless you want to perform something special for empty input).

In general, the `for` loop and and function that return another thing that you can iterate on will not give any "surprising behaviors" if you have an input of zero items. This includes `enumerate()` , `iteritems()`, and even slicing (`[][1:] == []`).

```
>>> list( enumerate([]) )
[]
>>> list( {}.iteritems() )
[]
>>> [][1:]
[]
>>> [x*x for x in []]
[]
```